# How to extract a specific word after # and before it ends? MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table **posts** and I need to extract specific tags from the column **description**.
I need to extract f.e. #sunny and #lovelyday and print it out separately from the full text description. For example:

> description: "today was a good day! #sunny #lovelyday" -> extract #sunny & #lovelyday

I searched for answers, but perhaps I do not understand it. (still learning)
PhpMyAdmin doesnt support, charindex() or len() -> so I tried locate() and length() but my query isn't correct.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(description, locate("#",description) + length("#")) AS Tags
from posts
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I need the "#%" from textfield and extract it

Comment: Do you know how many tags are in the message?  Sample data and desired results *as text tables* is preferred.

Comment: It always depends. A user can post as many tags he wants. I just need to extract all the tags with #.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> SET @string := 'today was a good day! #sunny #lovelyday';
> ```

> ```
> WITH RECURSIVE 
> cte AS ( SELECT 0 n
>          UNION ALL 
>          SELECT n + 1
>          FROM cte
>          WHERE n < (SELECT LENGTH(@string) - LENGTH(REPLACE(@string, '#', ''))))
> SELECT n, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@string, '#', -n), ' ', 1)
> FROM cte
> WHERE n;
> ```
>
> ```
>  n | SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@string, '#', -n), ' ', 1)
> -: | :---------------------------------------------------------
>  1 | lovelyday                                                 
>  2 | sunny
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ec48b3d3d235f79c48c98e73c85d8b6a)*

Comment: with recursive isnt working with phpmyadmin

Comment: @Mizugorou This does not depend on used client. Maybe your MySQL version is too ancient?